# Formalization of Analytic Number Theory

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

Is there any formalization, in any proof checking environment (Lean, Isabelle, etc.) of basic analytic number theory, say everything in a book like the Titchmarsh book (The Theory of the Riemann Zeta Function) or the Ingham book (The Distribution of Prime Numbers), or any equivalents?

Comment: A number of theorem provers have the prime number theorem.  See https://www.cs.ru.nl/~freek/100/

Comment: Also it appears the Archive of Formal Proofs in Isabelle/HOL has some of this stuff.  See https://www.isa-afp.org/entries/Zeta_Function.html.

Comment: @Jason Rute Of course it would help if I could include as tag words "analytic-number-theory" but the system does not allow it because I do not have 150 reputation points, which I think is totally silly ... as many things about the Stack platform are, but anyways, it is useful sometimes.

Comment: @Jason Rute If you follow the links in the second link you provided, it seems a good chunk of Apostol's book is formalized in Isabelle. That is already a good starting point. Basically, it takes you halfway there to formalizing Ingham, which is the smaller of the two books I mention, and in a way, also the more useful and unrepetitively complete for lots of other stuff. I wonder if anything like this is done in LEAN

Comment: I hesitate to give a formal answer since I don't know analytic number theory, but as for Lean, you can find out a lot on the Lean Zulip.  First, just search for the topics you are interested, and second ask in [Is there code for X?](https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/217875-Is-there-code-for-X.3F) specifically about analytic number theory.  (Or wait for someone more knowledgable than me to respond here.)  The impression I get is that this isn't really in mathlib yet, but is being slowly worked on, and might depend on some prerequisites.  You are likely welcome to pitch in.

Comment: @EGME On a side note it seems innapropriate to tag a question analytic-number-theory on this site, since it is really a reference request for some formalization and not a question about analytic number theory itself